# I am trying to compile my c program using cygwin gcc but I get an error when I try to do so

Tags: c, static-linking

When I try to compile my script I get the error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lecc
```

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:9: sample] Error 1

```
####################################

    HEADERS = eccapi.h

    default: sample

    sample.o: sample.c $(HEADERS)
        gcc -c sample.c -o sample.o

    sample: sample.o
        gcc sample.o -o sample -I./ -lecc

    clean:
        -rm -f sample.o
        -rm -f sample
```

#

```
/*After Add libecc.a file in the lib folder of my compiler, I'm getting some other error, below are the error */

    $ make
    gcc -c sample.c -o sample.o
    sample.c: In function ‘crypto_main’:
    sample.c:173:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘emberSerialGuaranteedPrintf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                 emberSerialGuaranteedPrintf(APP_SERIAL, "ZSE_ECCGenerateKey ERROR 0x%x\n",rc);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    gcc sample.o -o sample -I./ -lecc
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../libecc.a whe                    n searching for -lecc
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../libecc.a whe                    n searching for -lecc
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libecc.a when searching for -lecc
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libecc.a when searching for -lecc
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../libecc.a whe                    n searching for -lecc
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libecc.a when searching for -lecc
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lecc
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [Makefile:9: sample] Error 1
```

Comment: Show your *exact* compilation command. What is that `-lecc` ? What library do you want to link against? Where is that file?

Comment: Don't comment your own question, but **edit your question** to improve it. Show some [MCVE]. Consider showing your `Makefile`, as formatted text, in your question

Comment: Did you copy the libecc.a to /usr/lib? Use objdump or similar command to see if this is for you CPU, probably a 32-bit 64-bit issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're telling the compiler to link "libecc.a".  Either you do not have this library in your "lib" folder of your compiler, or you do not have the library in the path where your compiler looks.  Try adding -L to your linking step or check your lib folder and make certain you have that library.

**UPD**
Also notice that `error: ld returned 1 exit status` error is from linker. You can check if your required library `ecc` is installed [like this](https://serverfault.com/questions/54736/how-to-check-if-a-library-is-installed):

```
ldconfig -p | grep libecc
```